# FindFirst, FindNext (Delphi Xe, Win7) rank is not correct

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, rank, findfirst

I have some files in a directory. I try get these files with FindFirst and FindNext but I can't get same order on Windows 7.

```
C:\Test
SampleFile.0.png
SampleFile.1.png
SampleFile.2.png
SampleFile.3.png
SampleFile.4.png
SampleFile.5.png
SampleFile.6.png
SampleFile.7.png
SampleFile.8.png
SampleFile.9.png
SampleFile.10.png
SampleFile.11.png
SampleFile.12.png
SampleFile.13.png
SampleFile.14.png
SampleFile.15.png
SampleFile.16.png
SampleFile.17.png
SampleFile.18.png
SampleFile.19.png
SampleFile.20.png
SampleFile.21.png
SampleFile.22.png
```

When I try using my code I've got

```
SampleFile.0.png
SampleFile.1.png
SampleFile.10.png
SampleFile.11.png
SampleFile.12.png
SampleFile.13.png
SampleFile.14.png
SampleFile.15.png
SampleFile.16.png
SampleFile.17.png
SampleFile.18.png
SampleFile.19.png
SampleFile.2.png
SampleFile.20.png
SampleFile.21.png
.
.
.
```

How can I get file list on correct rank order?

```
Procedure Test;
var
sr : TSearchRec;
i : integer;
ListFiles : TStringList;  
begin
ListFiles := TStringList.Create;
i := FindFirst('c:\test\*.png', faDirectory, sr);
while i = 0 do begin  
ListFiles.Add(ExtractFileName(sr.FindData.cFileName));
i := FindNext(sr); 
end;
FindClose(sr);
end;
```

Note : Result is still wrong, if I can use ListFiles.Sorted = True

---

I think I've a solution, created a function.

```
function SortFilesByName(List: TStringList; Index1, Index2: Integer): integer;
var
FileName1, FileName2: String;
i, FileNumber1, FileNumber2: Integer;
begin
  FileName1 := ChangeFileExt(ExtractFileName(List[Index1]), '');
  FileName2 := ChangeFileExt(ExtractFileName(List[Index2]), '');
  i := POS('.', FileName1)+1;
  FileNumber1 := StrToInt(Copy(FileName1, i, MaxInt));
  i := POS('.', FileName2)+1;
  FileNumber2 := StrToInt(Copy(FileName2, i, MaxInt));
  Result := (FileNumber1 - FileNumber2);
end;
```

I've added another line 
      ListFiles.CustomSort(SortFilesByName); //(ListFiles,1,2):integer);
before
      FindClose(sr);

Answer (score 8):

As jachguate said, the sorting is done by Explorer.exe, not the filesystem.  FindFirst/FindNext does not guarantee any specific sorting, including plain ASCII based, so you shouldn't rely on it.  You don't, however, need to re-implement the numeric sort in Delphi.  Windows exposes the one it uses as [StrCmpLogicalW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which is in `shlwapi.dll`.  The import looks like this:

```
function StrCmpLogicalW(psz1, psz2: PWideChar): Integer; stdcall;
  external 'shlwapi.dll'
```

It is possible to disable that behavior in Windows.  If you want to follow the order that Windows uses, you need to call [SHRestricted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762245%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the `REST_NOSTRCMPLOGICAL` value.  If it returns true you should use AnsiCompareStr instead.

```
const
  // Use default CompareString instead of StrCmpLogical
  REST_NOSTRCMPLOGICAL = $4000007E;

function SHRestricted(rest: DWORD): LongBool; stdcall; external 'shell32.dll';
```

So your final sort function should be something like this:

```
function CompareFilenames(const AFilename1, AFilename2: string): Integer;
begin
  if SHRestricted(REST_NOSTRCMPLOGICAL) then
    Result := AnsiCompareStr(AFilename1, AFilename2)
  else
    Result := StrCmpLogicalW(PWideChar(AFilename1), PWideChar(AFilename2));
end;
```

You can cache the result of the SHRestricted call, but if you do you need to watch for the `WM_SETTINGSCHANGE` broadcast message and re-read it when you get one.

Answer (score 1):

The different orders you see in the windows explorer is implemented in explorer.exe and not in the file system.

The Numerical sort order is a new feature in windows 7, so if you sort *by name* and you have a bunch of files with a prefix followed by numbers, the explorer "identifies" that pattern and doesn't present a list sorted by name in the traditional way, but sorted by prefix and then by number (as if the string were a Integer number).

If you want to do the same in Delphi, you can do it by adding all the file names returned by FindFirst/FindNext to a TSlist and then sort the string list using this compare function:

```
var
  FileNames: TList<string>;
begin
  FileNames := TList<string>.Create;
  try
    SearchForFiles(FileNames); //here you add all the file names
    //sort file names a la windows 7 explorer
    FileNames.Sort(System.Generics.Defaults.TComparer<string>.Construct(
      function (const s1, s2: string): Integer
        procedure ProcessPrefix(const fn: string; var prefix, number: string);
        var
          I: Integer;
        begin
          for I := length(fn) downto 1 do
            if not TCharacter.IsDigit(fn[I]) then
            begin
              Prefix := Copy(fn, 1, I);
              number := Copy(fn, I+1, MaxInt);
              Break;
            end;
        end;
      var
        prefix1, prefix2: string;
        number1, number2: string;
        fn1, fn2: string;
      begin
        //compare filenames a la windows 7 explorer
        fn1 := TPath.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(s1);
        fn2 := TPath.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(s2);
        ProcessPrefix(fn1, prefix1, number1);
        ProcessPrefix(fn2, prefix2, number2);
        if (Number1 <> '') and (Number2 <> '') then
        begin
          Result := CompareText(prefix1, prefix2);
          if Result = 0 then
            Result := CompareValue(StrToInt(number1), StrToInt(Number2));
        end
        else
          Result := CompareText(s1, s2);
      end
      ));
    UseYourSortedFileNames(FileNames);
  finally
    FileNames.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

By "rank", you mean sort order.

The files are sorting in the proper order (based on the ASCII value of the characters). `2` comes after `19` because the comparison is only made up to the same number of characters in both names, and '2' comes after `1`.

If you want them to sort properly as numbers, you need to left-pad the numbers with zeros so they're all the same width (eg., instead of `SampleFile.2.png`, use `SampleFile.02.png`). This will cause '02' to come before `19` so they sort correctly numerically.

You can fix the numbering issue by using something like:

```
PngFileName := Format('SampleFile.%.2d.png', [Counter]);
```